# Getting error while python integration in Uipath

Tags: python, uipath

Following is my python script that I am trying to invoke in UiPath. But specifically on this line ‘table = tabulate(data,tablefmt=“plain”)’ it is throwing me error that Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all(). Anyone knows how to resolve this problem?

`

```
import sys
from tabula import read_pdf
from tabulate import tabulate
import pandas as pd
import io

def pdf_to_csv(file_path):
  # Read the only the page n°6 of the file
  data = read_pdf(file_path,pages = 'all',multiple_tables = True,stream = True,area=(94.03, 65.9,496.1, 969.36))
  # Transform the result into a string table format
  table = tabulate(data,tablefmt="plain")

  # Transform the table into dataframe
  df = pd.read_fwf(io.StringIO(table))

  df.to_csv('temp.csv',index=False,index_label=False,header=False)
```

`

Thanks in advance!

Tried multiple solutions available over stackoverflow. But none of them was helpful.

Comment: Please update the question to show the whole error traceback message.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and also link the "multiple solutions available over stackoverflow" that you tried, mention what exactly or why they didn't help. This way, don't have to start from zero.